# Как игнорировать "Подтвердите действие на странице" в браузере Google Chrome, библиотека selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо либо полностью игнорировать сообщение (исключить его появления на экране), либо нажимать "ОК" при появлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это из-за user agent силенум, измени юзер агент дабы система сайта принимала тебя за реального человека.